# link color clashes with background using MAGNIFY ODS style

Tags: sas, sas-ods

I recently switched from the HTML destination to HTML5 so I would get SVG graphics in a job, and everything looks lovely, except my table-of-contents links, which now have bad contrast against the dark background produced by the MAGNIFY style.  Dig how ugly these things are:

[image: near-unreadable links]

My call is:

```
ods html5 path      = "&qa_folder" (URL=NONE)
            body      = "ute_graphs.html"
            contents  = "toc.html"
            frame     = "index.html"
            (title    = "VDW Utilization Dataset Record Counts")
            style     = magnify
            nogfootnote
            nogtitle
            device = svg
            options(svg_mode="embed")
          ;
```

What's the easiest way I can recolor those (without ditching MAGNIFY)?

Comment: Change the template so that links are white? That may violate accessibility guidelines though.

Answer (score 2):

This generates the template:

```
proc template;
   source styles.magnify;
run;
```

Which is as follows:

```
proc template;
 define style Styles.Magnify_CUSTOM;
    parent = styles.default;
    style fonts /
       'TitleFont2' = ("Verdana, Helvetica, <sans-serif>, sans-serif",14pt,bold)
       'TitleFont' = ("Verdana, Helvetica, <sans-serif>, sans-serif",18pt,bold)
       'StrongFont' = ("Verdana, Helvetica, <sans-serif>, sans-serif",14pt,bold)
       'EmphasisFont' = ("Verdana, Helvetica, <sans-serif>, sans-serif",10pt,italic)
       'FixedEmphasisFont' = ("<monospace>, Courier, monospace",10pt,italic)
       'FixedStrongFont' = ("<monospace>, Courier, monospace",10pt,bold)
       'FixedHeadingFont' = ("<monospace>, Courier, monospace",10pt)
       'BatchFixedFont' = ("SAS Monospace, <monospace>, Courier, monospace",10pt)
       'FixedFont' = ("<monospace>, Courier, monospace",10pt)
       'headingEmphasisFont' = ("Verdana, Helvetica, <sans-serif>, sans-serif",14pt,bold italic)
       'headingFont' = ("Verdana, Helvetica, <sans-serif>, sans-serif",14pt,bold)
       'docFont' = ("Verdana, Helvetica, <sans-serif>, sans-serif",8pt,bold);
    class GraphFonts /
       'GraphDataFont' = ("Verdana, <MTsans-serif>",7pt)
       'GraphUnicodeFont' = ("<MTsans-serif-unicode>",9pt)
       'GraphFootnoteFont' = ("Verdana, <MTsans-serif>",10pt,bold)
       'GraphTitleFont' = ("Verdana, <MTsans-serif>",11pt,bold)
       'GraphTitle1Font' = ("Verdana, <MTsans-serif>",14pt,bold)
       'GraphValueFont' = ("Verdana, <MTsans-serif>",9pt)
       'GraphLabel2Font' = ("Verdana, <MTsans-serif>",10pt)
       'GraphLabelFont' = ("Verdana, <MTsans-serif>",10pt,bold)
       'GraphAnnoFont' = ("Verdana, <MTsans-serif>",10pt);
    style colors /
       'headerfgemph' = cxFFFFFF
       'headerbgemph' = cx387BB1
       'headerfgstrong' = cxFFFFFF
       'headerbgstrong' = cx387BB1
       'headerfg' = cxFFFFFF
       'headerbg' = cx387BB1
       'datafgemph' = cxFFFFFF
       'databgemph' = cx224764
       'datafgstrong' = cxFFFFFF
       'databgstrong' = cx224764
       'datafg' = cxFFFFFF
       'databg' = cx285375
       'batchfg' = cxFFFFFF
       'batchbg' = cx224764
       'tableborder' = cxFFFFFF
       'tablebg' = cx000000
       'notefg' = cxFFFFFF
       'notebg' = cx224764
       'bylinefg' = cxFFFFFF
       'bylinebg' = cx224764
       'captionfg' = cxFFFFFF
       'captionbg' = cx224764
       'proctitlefg' = cxFFFFFF
       'proctitlebg' = cx224764
       'titlefg' = cxFFFFFF
       'titlebg' = cx224764
       'systitlefg' = cxFFFFFF
       'systitlebg' = cx224764
       'Conentryfg' = cxFFFFFF
       'Confolderfg' = cxFFFFFF
       'Contitlefg' = cxFFFFFF
       'link2' = cxE3BC61
       'link1' = cxFEEDA2
       'contentfg' = cxFFFFFF
       'contentbg' = cx224764
       'docfg' = cxFFFFFF
       'docbg' = cx224764;
    class GraphColors /
       'gblockheader' = colors('docbg')
       'gcphasebox' = CXFFFFFF
       'gphasebox' = cxC2C9D8
       'gczonec' = cxB7C2DA
       'gzonec' = cxCBD3E3
       'gczoneb' = cxC0CBE4
       'gzoneb' = cxD2D9E9
       'gzonea' = cxDBE2F1
       'gcmiss' = cx84929e
       'gmiss' = cx4c687f
       'gablock' = colors('docbg')
       'gblock' = colors('docbg')
       'gcclipping' = cxDC531F
       'gclipping' = cxE7774F
       'gcstars' = cxFFFFFF
       'gstars' = cx2B599B
       'gcruntest' = cxBF4D4D
       'gruntest' = cxCAE3FF
       'gccontrollim' = cxFFFFFF
       'gcontrollim' = cx2B599B
       'gcerror' = cxFFFFFF
       'gerror' = cx2B599B
       'gcpredictlim' = cxACC1D8
       'gpredictlim' = cx2B599B
       'gcpredict' = cxACC1D8
       'gpredict' = cxACC1D8
       'gcconfidence2' = cxC9BDA0
       'gcconfidence' = cxACC1D8
       'gconfidence2' = cx9B7F2B
       'gconfidence' = cx2B599B
       'gcfit2' = cxC9BDA0
       'gcfit' = cxACC1D8
       'gfit2' = cxC9BDA0
       'gfit' = cxACC1D8
       'gcoutlier' = cxFFFFFF
       'goutlier' = cx2B599B
       'gcdata' = cxFFFFFF
       'gdata' = cx2B599B
       'ginsetheader' = colors('docbg')
       'ginset' = CX2E7787
       'greferencelines' = cxB9B9B9
       'gheader' = colors('docbg')
       'gout2cend' = cx3B82BC
       'gout2cstart' = cxFFFFFF
       'gconramp3cend' = cxE2746C
       'gconramp3cneutral' = cxE5E9EE
       'gconramp3cstart' = cx4FA3E7
       'gramp3cend' = cx7570B3
       'gramp3cneutral' = cxD95F02
       'gramp3cstart' = cxE3BC61
       'gconramp2cend' = cx99CCFF
       'gconramp2cstart' = cxFFFFFF
       'gramp2cend' = cx3B82BC
       'gramp2cstart' = cxFFFFFF
       'gtext' = CXFFFFFF
       'glabel' = CXFFFFFF
       'gborderlines' = CXFFFFFF
       'goutlines' = CXFFFFFF
       'gmgrid' = cx3E5C74
       'ggrid' = CX5F7D95
       'gaxis' = CXFFFFFF
       'gshadow' = CX000000
       'glegend' = CX173750
       'gfloor' = CX173750
       'gwalls' = cx173750
       'gckran5' = cx96CC64
       'gkran5' = cx7BB04A
       'gckran4' = cxD5E864
       'gkran4' = cxB8CC49
       'gckran3' = cxFFF567
       'gkran3' = cxF2D94B
       'gckran2' = cxFFAE5F
       'gkran2' = cxE09346
       'gckran1' = cxF0735D
       'gkran1' = cxD15845
       'gcdata12' = cxD9E168
       'gcdata11' = cxE2746C
       'gcdata10' = cx5A82AB
       'gcdata9' = cx956FC3
       'gcdata8' = cxC08C59
       'gcdata7' = cx9E6671
       'gcdata6' = cxE5E9EE
       'gcdata5' = cx79BD87
       'gcdata4' = cxFFF1B7
       'gcdata3' = cxB4BDEA
       'gcdata2' = cxFFD472
       'gcdata1' = cx4FA3E7
       'gdata12' = CXB6BC56
       'gdata11' = CXBD6059
       'gdata10' = CX3A5C7E
       'gdata9' = CX64559D
       'gdata8' = CXBE8A57
       'gdata7' = CX73434C
       'gdata6' = CXE0E4E7
       'gdata5' = CX5E996A
       'gdata4' = CXFEEDA2
       'gdata3' = CXAAB1D7
       'gdata2' = CXE3BC61
       'gdata1' = CX3B82BC;
    style Table from Output /
       cellpadding = 5
       borderwidth = 2
       bordercollapse = separate
       borderstyle = solid;
    style GraphCharts from GraphCharts
       "Chart Attributes" /
       transparency = 0.15;
    style GraphLabelText from GraphLabelText
       "Label attributes" /
       dropshadow = on;
    style GraphLabel2Text from GraphLabel2Text
       "Label attributes" /
       dropshadow = on;
    style GraphValueText from GraphValueText
       "Value attributes" /
       dropshadow = on;
    style GraphBackground from GraphBackground
       "Graph background attributes" /
       image = "Magnify.gif"
       textalign = left
       verticalalign = top;
    style GraphWalls from GraphWalls
       "Wall Attributes" /
       transparency = 1.0;
    style GraphLegendBackground from GraphLegendBackground
       "Legend Background Attributes" /
       transparency = 1.0;
    style GraphOther from GraphData12;
    style GraphInitial from GraphData11;
    style GraphFinal from GraphData12;
    style GraphOverflow from GraphData11;
    style GraphUnderflow from GraphData12;
 end;
run;
```

You can then play around with LINK1/LINK2 and use the MAGNIFY_CUSTOM as your style. If this doesn't work let me know and I'll test out the other way of modifying the template via a CLASS. The colour codes are in the format of hex codes, preceded by CX.

Comment: Ah--thanks! Unfortunately neither of those colors specified for LINK1 & LINK2 are the default blue that's being displayed (this is in both chrome & firefox btw). So it seems that the browser is not abiding by these styles, for some reason.  With the HTML destination it did but changing to HTML5 killed it.

Comment: For a goof I tried changing both of those to cxFFFFFF to try and turn them white, but it made no difference. I can see the CSS being generated properly, but for some reason, when I inspect it in chrome's dev tools, the color rules are lined-out. I think this is the default browser stylesheet being used.

Comment: Hmm...will check more into this.